# sIFR -> Semibold Font Problem

Tags: sifr

I'm trying to use Myriad Pro Semibold Condensed as my headline font. I've been able to get other states of the font to work, both Myriad Pro Regular and Myriad Pro Condensed work properly.

Here's what I'm seeing: http://php.saysoma.org/. As you can tell, the Regular and Condensed states work, but the third style, semibold condensed, is not visible.

Here's what I have in my sifr-config file:

```
sIFR.replace(myriad3, {
  selector: 'h4',
  css: [ 
  '.sIFR-root { letter-spacing: -1.2}'
  ,'a { text-decoration: none; }'
  ,'a:link { color: #000000; }'
  ,'a:hover { color: #772224; }'
 ],
  wmode: "Transparent"
});
```

And in my css file:

```
.sIFR-active h2, .sIFR-active h3, .sIFR-active h4 {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-family: Verdana;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

I'm using sIFR r436 and Flash CS4 to render the files.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After noticing that the third Flash object was only 10 px high, I was able to get the third line by adding style to your page:

```
* {height:42px!important;width:100%!important;float:left!important;display:block!important}
h4 {color:#ff0000}
```

This doesn't fix the problem, but it does show that it's a width/height issue. My understanding of sIFR is that it creates the flash object, and then expands the text size until it fills the bounding box. For whatever reason, your bounding box is too small on the third one.

Add some junk stuff to the page, make it more of a realistic layout. I think you are running up against some browser default sizes. Maybe try a CSS reset stylesheet too? Really, I think this might be a bug in sIFR, since your sample is so basic.

Comment: sIFR 3 uses the font size and resizes the bounding box if required. Not quite sure why it doesn't get any height though, might be a Flash issue with the font.

Comment: Hey Guys,
lod3n -> I tried your fix, but I never got it to work properly. After I threw in the layout, it broke the rest of the design.

Mark -> I think this may be it. I've found some threads on Adobe's website indicating problems w/ Myriad Pro Semibold Condensed. I think that's where the problem lies.

I tried Flash CS3 and CS4 on two different machines--both to the same result.

Thanks for your help, and let me know if you discover anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - could not make the font 'bold' style work, and I even wanted my fonts BlackItalic to work. Messing around and reading several posts and Marks answer made me try to apply the BlackItalic style to the very first word in the provided fla file ("Make"). Keeping the css style 'font-weight: normal;' in the config java code was successful!

I guess sIFR and flash have problems identifying some font-styles as bold, italic and so on. It seems like the first font style in the fla file is identified as 'font-weight: normal;' in the config-java-code.

Until I read some new posts about this I will follow the work flow making individual swf files for every font style - normally I only want to use one or to styles anyway.